# Вложенность меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

здравствуйте, у меня такой вопрос, у меня есть меню, в нем ul, в каждой ul есть li. Каждый последующий элемент зависит по высоте от дочки

```
 function cheked_heights(){
  console.log('> cheked_heights')
  var subcat = $('.subcat') // место в DOM  где находится нужное меню
  var ul_lvl_1 = subcat.children('ul') // ul - 1-ого уровня
  var ul_lvl_1_height = ul_lvl_1.height() // высота этого ul
  var li_lvl_1 = ul_lvl_1.children('li') // все li, которые находяься в ul 1-ого уровня
  li_lvl_1.each(function(i,d){ // перебор всех li
    var li = $(d) //все li 1-ого уровня у ul
    var ul = li.children('ul') // у каждой li есть свой ul
    ul.attr('style', 'min-height: ' + ul_lvl_1_height + 'px;') //
  })

}
```

Как использовать переменные li и ul для lvl_2 ?

```
function cheked_heights(){
  console.log('> cheked_heights')
  var subcat = $('.subcat') // место в DOM  где находится нужное меню
  var ul_lvl_1 = subcat.children('ul') // ul - 1-ого уровня
  var ul_lvl_1_height = ul_lvl_1.height() // высота этого ul
  var li_lvl_1 = ul_lvl_1.children('li') // все li, которые находяься в ul 1-ого уровня
  li_lvl_1.each(function(i,d){ // перебор всех li
    var li = $(d) //все li 1-ого уровня у ul
    var ul = li.children('ul') // у каждой li есть свой ul
    ul.attr('style', 'min-height: ' + ul_lvl_1_height + 'px;') //

    var li_lvl_2 = ul.children('li') //*
     li_lvl_2.each(function(i,d))   //*
  })

}
```

Можно продолжить вложенность вот так, (где *), но у меня в менюшке всплывающих подменюшек 5, т.е это немного неправильно

Comment: Что в итоге надо сделать?

Comment: Нужно,чтобы высота ul родителя была равна высоте ul дочернего. Вложенность такая : div.subcat   ul > li   ul > li

Comment: высоте одного дочернего или максимального? или сумме высот всех дочерних?

Comment: Сделал, спасибо)